# Restrict content in a div to two lines only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have large text as in attached image

before applying CSS

[image: Before Applying CSS]

As per requirment , need to restrict showing data to two lines only . For that I am using below css code

```
     { display: -webkit-box;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space : normal;
        width : 100%
}
     After Applying Above CSS
```

[image: After Applying above CSS]

But client is asking for output as below

Expecting ..

[image: Expected]

Please someone help on this

Comment: Your statement is unclear, it looks like your container width is not long enough?

Comment: Could you please explain the difference between the output you got and the client requirement. Apart from the extra ellipsis.

Comment: Please be careful because `-webkit-line-clamp, -webkit-box-orient` won't work in firefox and others. see https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

Comment: Question has been modified , please help

Comment: Using ellipsis to "dot out" text only works for single lines.

Comment: In your Image Second line after SunLife everything is one word as there is no space between "Event2018LifeRoad" - Try changing it to  "Event 2018 Life Road"  and check.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok.
you will have to define width as you need.

```
{  
 display:-webkit-box;
 -webkit-line-clamp:3;
 -webkit-box-orient:vertical;  
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 160px;
}
```